# how do i know if a submodule has changed in git?

Tags: git, git-submodules

Currently I have a few submodules in my parent project.  How can I tell if one of the submodules has recently changed and I need to do a

```
git submodule foreach git pull origin master
```

Comment: what's wrong with what you're currently doing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Submodules are nothing more then nested git repositories.

Try this command, I don't have any repositories with submodules to test it on.

```
git submodule foreach 'echo $path `git status`'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
git pull --recurse-submodules=yes
```